# Does php autoloader cache results>

Tags: php, caching, autoload

I'm a little confused. I have code that looks like this:

```
var_dump(class_exists ("blah\myclass"));
include_once("Autoloader.php"); //this file creates the function, and does spl_autoload_register('Autoloader::loader');

var_dump(class_exists ("blah\myclass")); //line3
spl_autoload_unregister('Autoloader::loader');

var_dump(class_exists ("blah\myclass"));
```

I expected the output to show: 
  `false`, `true`, `false`.

But I'm getting: 
  `false`, `true`, `true`.

At first, I thought maybe I just wasn't unregistering correctly, but if I take out line 3, I get what I'd expect:
  `false`, `false`

I'm trying to understand what's going on.  Is PHP caching the class definition the first time it instantiates the class?  And if so, does that mean `spl_autoload_unregister` is no longer useful after the 1st time the class is found?

Thanks for any clarifications.

Comment: Once PHP is aware of the class it will remain aware of it. The autoloader's purpose is just to find it dynamically.

Comment: You can also try composer for autoloading

Comment: So does this mean that the spl_autoload_unregister() function is basically useless after the 1st time the class is found?

Comment: spl_autoload_unregister prevents future classes from being found.